# How do I filter rows depending on values in semi-colon separated columns?

Tags: r, data.table

I have a table that looks like this:

```
> dt
                   variant_id           transcript_id         0       1     2
    1: chr17_45630589_C_A_b38 chr17_46031704_46032046   1584;41  891;27 146;5
    2: chr17_45630589_C_A_b38 chr17_46032300_46033079    782;41  438;27  76;5
    3: chr17_45630589_C_A_b38 chr17_46033193_46033402    988;41  620;27 116;5
    4: chr17_45630589_C_A_b38 chr17_46033461_46034160   1162;41  725;27 133;5
    5: chr17_45630589_C_A_b38 chr17_46033470_46034160      0;41    0;27   0;5
   ---
37392:  chr9_34699703_G_C_b38  chr9_34648457_34648761 24060;256 2644;36  <NA>
37393:  chr9_34699703_G_C_b38  chr9_34648895_34648997 35276;256 3512;36  <NA>
37394:  chr9_34699703_G_C_b38  chr9_34648908_34648997   336;256   60;36  <NA>
37395:  chr9_34699703_G_C_b38  chr9_34649082_34649409 33640;256 3400;36  <NA>
37396:  chr9_34699703_G_C_b38  chr9_34649565_34650368 45540;256 4708;36  <NA>
```

I want to only extract the rows where the first semi-colon separated value under `0` equals `0` and the first semicolon-separated value in `1` and `2` is greater than 0, preferably where `2` is greater than `1`. I've attempted to do this myself but it has resulted in a new column with values other than 0:

```
> test
                   variant_id           transcript_id         0       1     2
    1: chr17_45630589_C_A_b38 chr17_46031704_46032046   1584;41  891;27 146;5
    2: chr17_45630589_C_A_b38 chr17_46032300_46033079    782;41  438;27  76;5
    3: chr17_45630589_C_A_b38 chr17_46033193_46033402    988;41  620;27 116;5
    4: chr17_45630589_C_A_b38 chr17_46033461_46034160   1162;41  725;27 133;5
    5: chr17_45630589_C_A_b38 chr17_46033470_46034160      0;41    0;27   0;5
   ---
37392:  chr9_34699703_G_C_b38  chr9_34648457_34648761 24060;256 2644;36  <NA>
37393:  chr9_34699703_G_C_b38  chr9_34648895_34648997 35276;256 3512;36  <NA>
37394:  chr9_34699703_G_C_b38  chr9_34648908_34648997   336;256   60;36  <NA>
37395:  chr9_34699703_G_C_b38  chr9_34649082_34649409 33640;256 3400;36  <NA>
37396:  chr9_34699703_G_C_b38  chr9_34649565_34650368 45540;256 4708;36  <NA>
       0_new   1_new 2_new
    1:     0  891,27 146,5
    2:     0  438,27  76,5
    3:     0  620,27 116,5
    4:     0  725,27 133,5
    5:     1    0,27   0,5
   ---
37392:     0 2644,36    NA
37393:     0 3512,36    NA
37394:     0   60,36    NA
37395:     0 3400,36    NA
37396:     0 4708,36    NA
```

It also very flatly doesn't work the way I want it to. How do I go about doing this?

Edit:

```
> dput(head(as.data.frame(dt)))
structure(list(variant_id = c("chr17_45630589_C_A_b38", "chr17_45630589_C_A_b38",
"chr17_45630589_C_A_b38", "chr17_45630589_C_A_b38", "chr17_45630589_C_A_b38",
"chr17_45630589_C_A_b38"), transcript_id = c("chr17_46031704_46032046",
"chr17_46032300_46033079", "chr17_46033193_46033402", "chr17_46033461_46034160",
"chr17_46033470_46034160", "chr17_46034280_46038537"), `0` = c("1584;41",
"782;41", "988;41", "1162;41", "0;41", "5;41"), `1` = c("891;27",
"438;27", "620;27", "725;27", "0;27", "4;27"), `2` = c("146;5",
"76;5", "116;5", "133;5", "0;5", "0;5")), row.names = c(NA, 6L
), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Added the `data.table` tag, Edit to remove it if it's not what you're using.

Comment: When you say 1 and 2 are greater than 0, is it any value?

Comment: What is the expected output for the `dput`

Comment: I have updated the question with `dput`

Comment: @akrun yes, these are values, any value greater than 0. So let's say we found a row where the first semi-colon separated value in column `0` `== 0`, it would be correct if the corresponding value for `1` `== 4921` and `2` `== 10324`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is equivalent to the first character of the `0` column being "0" and the first character of the `1` and `2` columns not being 0 or minus.  Here `dt` is a data.table. With this approach we don't have to split up the values.

```
dt[grepl("^0", `0`) & !grepl('^[-0]', `1`) & !grepl('^[-0]', `2`)]
```

In the question there are no negative values and if we knew that the values are never negative, in general, it could be simplified to:

```
dt[grepl("^0", `0`) & !grepl('^0', `1`) & !grepl('^0', `2`)]
```

or

```
dt[startsWith(`0`, "0") & !startsWith(`1`, "0") & !startsWith(`2`, "0")]
```

Answer (score 3):

Extract 1st values as numeric for columns 0, 1, and 2. Then filter as usual:

```
dt[, paste0("firstValue_", 0:2) := lapply(.SD, function(i) tstrsplit(i, split = ";", type.convert = TRUE)[[ 1 ]]), .SDcol = 3:5] 

dt
#                variant_id           transcript_id       0      1     2 firstValue_0 firstValue_1 firstValue_2
# 1: chr17_45630589_C_A_b38 chr17_46031704_46032046 1584;41 891;27 146;5         1584          891          146
# 2: chr17_45630589_C_A_b38 chr17_46032300_46033079  782;41 438;27  76;5          782          438           76
# 3: chr17_45630589_C_A_b38 chr17_46033193_46033402  988;41 620;27 116;5          988          620          116
# 4: chr17_45630589_C_A_b38 chr17_46033461_46034160 1162;41 725;27 133;5         1162          725          133
# 5: chr17_45630589_C_A_b38 chr17_46033470_46034160    0;41   0;27   0;5            0            0            0
# 6: chr17_45630589_C_A_b38 chr17_46034280_46038537    5;41   4;27   0;5            5            4            0

# now filter
dt[ firstValue_0 == 0 & firstValue_0 > 1 & firstValue_2 > 1, ]
```

Note: based on your example data there are no rows that match this condition.